# Google sheets. Generate sequence ID

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence

I need to generate "ID" in quantity which is given in "quantity" column.

I use the formula "=ArrayFormula(TOCOL("T"&TEXT( sequence(C2);"00")&""&$A2&"|"&$B2))".
It generates ID only for the first product. How to generate IDs for the entire ID array?
[Example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iFI0_mzQc6pEq5Db1ob0_7_sGzVDVQTIuPez9cAuDmI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=tocol(map(A2:A;B2:B;C2:C;lambda(a;b;c;if(counta({a\b\c})<>3;;index("T"&text(sequence(1;c);"00")&a&"|"&b))));1)
```

[image]